# Is there a pejorative term or phrase that lesbians use to refer to straight women?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, slang, offensive-language, pejorative-language

Is there a pejorative term or phrase that lesbians use to refer to straight women?  There seems to be a wealth of terms (both offensive and inoffensive) that are used in the other direction. I ask because two lesbian employers of my wife were expressing disgust at some of her sexual practices (don't worry, I am not going to go into detail). If there exists such visceral disgust, it seems as if words or phrases would have been coined to express it.  I will not ask the two principals of this discussion since that would require bringing back up an uncomfortable conversation that should have probably never happened in a "professional" environment.

Comment: There's always _breeders_, which is a disparaging term used for straight people in general. It's not gender-specific, neither of the speaker or the person being described.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Shouldn't you be writing this as an answer rather than a comment? That said, I think this is a good answer.

Comment: @Louel, I only added it as a comment since it doesn't exactly answer the question, in that it's not specifically/exclusively a word _lesbians_ would use about straight _women_ (not that such a word necessarily even exists).

Answer (score 6):

I can't think of a term that lesbians exclusively use to describe straight women, but there are terms used to describe acts that, obviously, only heterosexual women (and gay men) will do. It isn't hard to imagine lesbians using these to spite straight women.

There's the sexual slur "sword swallower" (originally Australian, 1800s), as well as the extremely vulgar term "cocksucker"--a woman (or a man for that matter) who performs oral sex on men (obviously, lesbians won't do this).

There are terms such as "one-way" (used in the gay community in the 1960s, US) , "het" and "breeder"-- all three are terms referring to "a straight person".

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_sexual_slurs.